# Simple date_sub() mySQL Query failing to execute

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the Query I'm attempting to execute just to no avail

```
SELECT 
    p.*, c.* 
FROM 
    `players` AS `p` 
INNER JOIN 
    `price_checks` AS `c` 
ON 
    `c`.`resourceId` = `p`.`Player_Resource` 
WHERE 
    DATE(`c`.`timecheck`) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND 
    `p`.`Players_id` = '16892'
```

The error I'm being shown is the following

```
SELECT p.*, c.* FROM `players` AS `p` INNER JOIN `price_checks` AS `c` ON `c`.`resourceId` = `p`.`Player_Resource` WHERE DATE(`c`.`timecheck`) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND `p`.`Players_id` = '16892' 
LIMIT 0, 25 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2
```

It's saying that I'm appending a LIMIT syntax? Any reason as to why it could be failing?

Comment: its probaly you are in the wrong query :) . mysql doesnt Lie , look other queries where you have LIMIT 0,25.

Comment: I've gone ahead and shown the complete error thrown when performing through phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Curtis . . . could you have a semicolon at the end of the `where` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have missing `)`

```
     DATE(`c`.`timecheck`) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
                                                                  ^--here
```

**REASON:** mysql was looking for `)` then it comes `LIMIT` and `)` didnt come yet, so he gets surprised why LIMIT comes now :) , then it told you ayyy , Heyy !! is it missing something in the right Of LIMIT :). ?